# Lifespan of an APPLE SSD SM0256F?

Tags: mac, ssd, lifespan

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me the approximate lifespan of Apple's Latest MacBook's SSD Disks -- APPLE SSD SM0256F. What would be the lifespan I could expect?

Also, is this a Single layer disk (lesser lifespan) or a Multi Layer Disk (longer lifespan)?

I really want a longer lifespan so could you tell me what lifespan I could expect? Also, any tips on increasing its lifespan?

These SSD's are PCIe based and are found in the latest versions of MacBook Pros (Late 2013) and MacBook Airs (Early 2014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SM0256F uses MLC so it should have a longer lifespan than devices uses TLC NAND. It's basically a Samsung XP941. There are no official endurance specifications, as far as I know, but devices using the same technology are typically rated at 70TB or so (40GB/day for 5 years).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's too late to help, but for further reference about SM0256F - from my experience, 2 years is what you should reasonably expect.

My 2014 MBP was purchased in January 2014, with SM0256F; it failed in mid December 2015.

Comment: What was your usage like???? A lot of read/writes????? Also, Thank you so so so much for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I too might be a little late to answer, but I'd like to share my story with my SM0256F. I bought a used Late 2013 iMac back in early 2017, and the original owner had it in a Fusion Drive setup. When I installed [DriveDX](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) and checked the drive's detailed S.M.A.R.T. info, I saw the drive already had ~120TB written! It was still working fine, but it did feel a little sluggish overall. I removed the Fusion setup and used the SSD as my boot drive only.

Fast forward to today; DriveDX gave me the notification we all fear - my SSD was failing. I checked the Host Writes and realized the drive had written over 500TB of data! (502.7, to be exact) I bought a new SATA SSD and a USB enclosure and `dd`ed the data from the SM0256F to the new drive (I don't want to open my iMac yet because it requires cutting and readhering the display with thin tape - can be dangerous without a lot of precision and patience). I erased the SM0256F afterwards to keep the issue of matching UUIDs away.

I think the reason it wrote so much is that I was, nearly all the time, maxing out the system's RAM (16GB). The largest amount of memory the swapfile was using, from what I recall, was about 36GB. 36GB of continuous writing and erasing.

In conclusion, my SM0256F took quite a beating for its capacity. I tend to take good care of SSDs because of their limited write cycles, but beware of the system abusing the drive on its own. If you're as lucky as me, you'll have the thing for quite a while before it needs to be replaced.

Cheers!

Comment: Followup: I was forced to open the computer and remove the failing SSD because my computer would kernel panic frequently when left idle. I am in the process of assembling it again, I will return with later results to see if that resolved it.